# Is there a system variable which reflects the current visual studio version?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am using Visual Studio Code and have to specify the Visual Studio's `include` folder in my project settings to get the Intellisense:

`"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.12.25827/include/*"`

The problem is, the version keeps changing as I update Visual Studio. Is there a way to set it once and forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use globbing operators in path? Replace version which is changing with * or combination of digits and *.

Another solution is to use Windows SDK which for given Windows build version will have it's include paths constant and you would simple change path if you want to target different Windows SDK version. All Windows SDK do install side by side so you can have as many build environments as you wish.